# Why RedirectToAction() does not stop the current action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I got a problem with visual studio 2013. I have two actions in my controller: ActionResult VerifyRequest and ActionResult b.

```
    public ActionResult VerifyRequest()
       {
                    Utility.SessionKeys sessionKeys = new Utility.SessionKeys();
                    Session.Add(sessionKeys.InvoiceNumber, result.OrderId);
                    payment.TrackingCode = result.VerifyResultData.SystemTraceNo;
                    payment.state = 3;
                    payment.Confirmed = true;
                    payment.Transactionsuccess = true;
                    db.Entry(payment).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    melliBank.ResCode = result.VerifyResultData.ResCode;
                    melliBank.OrderId = result.VerifyResultData.OrderId;
                    melliBank.RetrivalRefNo = result.VerifyResultData.RetrivalRefNo;
                    melliBank.SystemTraceNo = result.VerifyResultData.SystemTraceNo;
                    melliBank.InvoiceDate = payment.IssueDate;
                    melliBank.Succeed = result.VerifyResultData.Succeed;
                    melliBank.Amount = result.VerifyResultData.Amount;
                    melliBank.Description = result.VerifyResultData.Description;
                    melliDB.InsertMelliBankLog(melliBank);
                    ReservType reserv = db.ReservTypes.Find(payment.ReserveType);
                    //string url = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}{3}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~"), reserv.ConfirmUrl);
                    //return Redirect(url);
                    return RedirectToAction(reserv.ConfirmUrl.Split('/')[1], reserv.ConfirmUrl.Split('/')[0]);
                }

    public ActionResult b()
       {
          return View();
       }
```

Here is the deal:
When i use RedirectToAction("b") from action "VerifyRequest" to action b after return action "VerifyRequest" execute again. And also when action b get completes, action "VerifyRequest" execute again too.
I don't know how to solve this problem and what is bug. Please help me. 
Sometimes "VerifyRequest" execute 4 times after redirect

Comment: It is rather strange to see your case... perhaps it has something to do with real name for action `a` and `b` as MVC works on naming convention and probably `a` is the default route?

Comment: actually these names are sample. in my controller i use different names

Comment: That's it.. I mean. I got something to do with your `real name` and how you route them...

Comment: please post a [mcve]. also when you do a redirect `a` is done and responded to.

Comment: ok i paste a sample suppose it redirects to action b

Comment: @– Daniel A. White yes i know it should be done and finish.but the problem is that it is not finished

Comment: That's not an mcve.

Comment: from where you calling VerifyRequest() method, show how you are calling this.

Comment: it's been called from another service .from bank service

Comment: @NineBerry  what was negative for??

Comment: It's not a good question. It does not contain an mvce. It is not possible for anyone to know what is going wrong.

Comment: the codes inside the action are not important. the importan thing is that after redirect the current action starts from the begining

Answer (score 0):

For RedirectToAction we have to pass actionmethod name
try this:-

```
return RedirectToAction("b);
```